# How can I print a linked list by using <ul> in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, html-lists

I want to print the following table data using `<ul>` element.

```
#id    Category      Parent 
1      Electronics     null
2      Food            null
3      TV              1
4      Burger          2
5      Cake            2
```

Just like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>Electronics
        <ul>
            <li>TV</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Food
        <ul>
            <li>Burger</li>
            <li>Cake</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

---

- Electronics

  - TV
- Food

  - Burger
  - Cake

I'm using Codeigniter framework (PHP). Tried with a recursive function, but no luck.

Comment: add you data array with print_r option

Comment: why don't you use `<table>` for this layout?

Comment: Where is your data? did you fetch them and saved in an associative array ?

Comment: yes, i have the whole table data in an associative multi-dimensional array called $categories @RalphMelhem

Comment: because i need the table data printed inside an `<ul>` element @rhgb

Comment: is this mapping table

Comment: you have to use recursive function for this.

Comment: here parent is primary of other table?

Comment: Yes, I tried recursive @NiranjanNRaju

Comment: No, parent is the id from the same table @MayankVadiya

Comment: I am testing it on my server and will post my answer

Comment: Yes, please. Thanks :) @RalphMelhem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my code. It can be optimized, but it does the job for now :) :

```
echo'<ul>';
foreach($categories as $value)
{
    if($value['Parent'] == null)
    {
        echo '<li>'.$value['Category'];
        $noChildren = true;

        foreach ($categories as $subValue) 
        {
            if($subValue['Parent'] == $value['id'])
            {
                if($noChildren == true)
                {
                    $noChildren = false;
                    echo '<ul>';
                }
                echo'<li>'.$subValue['Category'].'</li>';
            }
        }

        if ($noChildren == false)
        {
            echo'</ul>';
        }
    }
}
echo'</ul>';
```

Comment: Your solution gave an idea though similar to my idea (recursive). 
It doesn't print the whole table. I need a recursive solution.My table data are not fixed, they are dynamic. Categories are multi-level.